# VBA to select range and then resize range size

Tags: excel, vba, resize, range

I need to select all values in a given given range and then add 3 rows.

Here is the code I have but I can't seem to figure out how to get the `resize` to work.  I get runtime error 1004.

Essentially, I need to select all values from C4 down and then add 3 additional rows to the range. There are a two blank cells and then a total cell(see sample data below).

```
Sub Resize_Range()

Range(Range("C4"), Range("C4").End(xlDown)).Resize(3, 0).Select

End Sub



Cell    Value
C4      Animal
C5      Dog
C6      Cat
C7      Panda
C8      Horse
C9  
C10 
C11     Total
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use Resaize as that will resize the range to that size not add rows.

Just add 3 to the last row found using offset:

```
Range(Range("C4"), Range("C4").End(xlDown).Offset(3,0)).Select
```

I assume this is just for a future use, but remember the use of `.Select` slows down the code and 99% of the time can be skipped.

Also remember that assigning parentage to all range objects is important so VBA is not defaulting to activesheet.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
     .Range(.Range("C4"), .Range("C4").End(xlDown).Offset(3,0)).Value = "Test"
End With
```

Comment: So simple...Thanks!

Comment: How would I delete the range without using `.select` as an example?  `Sub Resize_andDelete()

Dim rng1 As Range

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    rng1 = Range(Range("B5"), Range("B5").End(xlDown).Offset(3, 0))
    rng1.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    
End Sub`  This code results in an error.

Comment: I forgot to add `set` to the code and it now works `Sub Resize_andDelete() Dim rng1 As Range Sheets("Sheet1").Select set rng1 = Range(Range("B5"), Range("B5").End(xlDown).Offset(3, 0)) rng1.Delete Shift:=xlUp End Sub`